# WordPress site displaying 404 for any page apart from index

Tags: htaccess, 404-error, rewrite-rules, nginx

My WordPress site is returning a 404 not found error on any page apart from the homepage and /wp-admin. I have no absolutely no idea why this is. My Permalinks are set up to use `/year/month/date/post-title/` (e.g `www.domain.com/2014/04/28/sample-post/`). When I change the permalinks to the default (`?p=123`) it works fine, but not on any of the other ones. 
Here is the contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have also installed the plugin 'Debug This', which provides details on the Rewrite Rules. However because it's a pretty big list and unformatted it would look quite bad, I've put it in a jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8PHD/embedded/result/

I think that's all the details I have, I've disabled all plugins and stuff like that. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: ok so I've since discovered a bit more info. I also forgot to say that the host for the site is Heroku (I'm building for a client and for some reason he's insisting I use Heroku, which is bad choice for WP I know but I can't persuade him otherwise so that's life). I recently installed [`heroku-buildpack-php-tyler`](https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler), which also installed Nginx. So I'm assuming that's whats broken my Permalinks. I then found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695387/nginx-404-not-found-page-for-permalinks), which seems to be about the issue I'm having, which links to this page on the Nginx Documentation. Problem is I've never used Nginx before so I don't know where to put all the code it's got in the first section entitled Abridged Basic Setup. Can someone help me out? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your server does not have [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled
2. Or you do not have [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) set correctly to allow your
   `.htaccess` file to operate correctly. You will need `AllowOverride` set to at least `FileInfo`.

I'd bet on the latter, as `mod_rewrite` is pretty ubiquitous.

Based on your edit, the issue is that Nginx doesn't use `.htaccess` files. My experience with Nginx is limited but rewrite rules are written into server configuration files, I believe. [The Codex has a page on the topic.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)

Comment: thanks for the input, I've added more info to the post I've since found out which hopefully will be more useful :)