# Permalinks/Pretty links aren't working on my site

Tags: permalinks

I have kind of a complicated setup.  When you go to my [website](http://agentc0re.com) you can see that on the menu bar each place is Home|Blog|Forum ... etc.  Each of those are part of rewrite rules.  IE:  Blog is actually index.php?page=blog.php FWIW in my code i wrote it so it hides the .php of those files.

So, going to my Blog section, where wordpress resides you will see that it does indeed display the default setup for wordpress.  I know the page formatting is off, but that is because i'm trying to fix this first.

Here is my wordpress .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks +Includes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI -MultiViews -Indexes
<files .htaccess>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you click "Read More" in the page post, it redirects you to /admin/hello-world/ but the redirection is a 404 not found.  I dunno why this is.

Your help will be much appreciated and will save the other half of my hair that is left on my head. :D

-Jon

Comment: There is no "redirect" to `/admin`. The link being generated is already an `/admin/` link. What is the code that creates that creates the link? What else have you modified?

Comment: I have no clue what code creates the /admin/hello-world/ links as it's a permalink setting in wordpress.  i set the custom permalink to /%author%/%postname%/.

Comment: Well, that answered the question whether you meant to or not :) Have you switched to a bundled theme to see if the problem occurs there too?

Comment: Hahhah.  Im glad it did answer it.  No i have not tried switching to a bundled theme.  What do you mean by bundled theme or i guess the better question is, where do i get one so i can try.   Oh and I am using a theme other than what came with wordpress.  It's called DarkElements IIRC.

Comment: I googled after i asked. :P  Looks like what i saw from my quick search is that bundled themes cost $$$.  I'm almost positive that this is a rewrite rule issue.  I just don't know what to fix.

Comment: No, bundled themes ship with WordPress, and they are free. They are all called "Twenty-Something" now. Try one of those, just to check.

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It is in side my wordpress installation directory.

Comment: Try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142733/21376

Comment: Took a look at it and it didn't really seem helpful to my problem.  :/  Sorry.  Should i most more of my rewrite rules for you to take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to change, which was so stupidly simple, was my wordpress .htaccess file to this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../index.php?page=blog [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

A few issues remain unanswered but i'm calling this an answer to my main question about getting Pretty Permalinks working with my site.